# a slide show for text exclusively / that plays constantly / but with image files for the "back", "stop" & "forward" buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, slideshow

i'm looking for a slide show exclusively   for text attached to css / that plays constantly / but with image files for the "back", "stop" & "forward" buttons.

I've searched for 3 days for something practical  for a slide show that could be practical for a text scenario exclusively. What I've found were mostly javascript slide show's that were mainly for images & i'm not experienced enough to modify them for text attached to css.

the scenario im currently stuck with is 4 paragraphs in a div css overflow... not going to fly ascetically or in a appealing sense for my targeted audience.

****the scenario i'm hoping to have, is for * 4 paragraphs ( 4 layers in the ss, preferably DIV tags so i can add css on a external style sheet) * have the slide show perpetually playing * image files on the left and right for " back " & "forward " buttons.* and a image file on the bottom for a " stop" button** ***

if someone could give me a functional code & to educated me on where in the HTML to insert each portion of the code i'd greatly appreciate it , I've been searching since Thursday and here i am still looking on a Saturday morning !

o yea , i guess i could do this in fireworks but the only option i see is for FLASH & i don't want to go that route . i JUST DOWNLOADED adobe EDGE , maybe i experiment with this... i was hoping for JavaScript of something similar THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link, http://bxslider.com/. Then this http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls. I think this is what you need?
 Create folowing html:

```
<div id="slider1">
  <div>Slide one content</div>
  <div>Slide two content</div>
  <div>Slide three content</div>
  <div>And so on...</div>
</div>
```

Then add next to your html head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
      auto: true,
      autoControls: true
    });
  });
</script>
```